# Manipulate system clipboard via bash script

Tags: linux, bash, clipboard

Is it possible to have a bash script put some text in the system clipboard?

(I use Ubuntu with default Gnome and Bash.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a commandline tool `xclip` .
**Example:** Copy output of the following command to clipboard:

```
$ sort -n -k 3, -k 2 file.txt | xclip
```

Tutorial: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/xclip-linux-insert-files-command-output-intoclipboard/

Comment: Accepted, for I could install it via my package manager. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it on my own, but there is a Bash Clipboard Interactive Script project on SourceForge: http://bics.sourceforge.net/